# Group a large list of dictionaries by key value in django

Tags: python, django

I have a list of dictionaries as follows

```
[{'grade': '1', 'past_student_sum': 1611}, 
 {'grade': '2', 'past_student_sum': 1631}, 
 {'grade': '3', 'past_student_sum': 1598}, 
 {'grade': '1', 'current_student_sum': 1611}, 
 {'grade': '2', 'current_student_sum': 1631}, 
 {'grade': '3', 'current_student_sum': 1598}]
```

I got this list by combining 2 query sets in the following fashion:

```
grade_list = list(past_enrollments) + list(current_enrollments)
```

Is there a better alternatives to combine these in such a way to get a list that looks like this:

```
[{'grade': '1', 'past_student_sum': 1611, 'current_student_sum': 1621},
 {'grade': '2', 'past_student_sum': 1511, 'current_student_sum': 1521}]
```

Comment: is it a coincidence that the `'past_student_sum'` and `'current_student_sum'` **always** have the same value for corresponding grades?

Comment: Yes. This is just dummy data. But in reality sometimes they will be the same, other times they will be different.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of building a list of dictionaries from `past_enrollments` and `current_enrollments`, I would instead build  another dictionary using the `grade` value as a key.  The easiest way to do this would probably be with a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import chain

grades = defaultdict(dict)

for d in chain(past_enrollments, current_enrollments):
    grades[d['grade']].update(d)
```

Then our finished dictionaries are just the values of that dictionary

```
grades = list(grades.values())
print(grades)
# [{'grade': '1', 'past_student_sum': 1611, 'current_student_sum': 1611}, 
#  {'grade': '2', 'past_student_sum': 1631, 'current_student_sum': 1631}, 
#  {'grade': '3', 'past_student_sum': 1598, 'current_student_sum': 1598}]
```

Comment: what are `past_enrollments` and `current_enrollments` in your snippet?

Comment: @Ev.Kounis Whatever they are in the question?  Some iterables containing dictionaries, presumably.

Comment: Oh, I missed that. In that case, this is my favorite answer! Nice

Answer (score 2):

Here's one solution using a dict to group and merge the records by `grade`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

grade_map = defaultdict(dict)
for grade_info in grade_list:
    grade_map[grade_info['grade']].update(grade_info)
print(list(grade_map.values()))
```

Comment: Did you get the desired result when you tried running this?

Comment: Nah, I just realized this is not enough

Comment: Updated the example now

Answer (score 1):

This might help.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

d = [{'grade': '1', 'past_student_sum': 1611},
 {'grade': '2', 'past_student_sum': 1631},
 {'grade': '3', 'past_student_sum': 1598},
 {'grade': '1', 'current_student_sum': 1611},
 {'grade': '2', 'current_student_sum': 1631},
 {'grade': '3', 'current_student_sum': 1598}]

e = {}
for i in d:
    if i["grade"] not in e:
        e[i["grade"]] = i
    else:
        if i.get("current_student_sum", None):
            e[i["grade"]].update({"current_student_sum": i["current_student_sum"]})

print [i[1] for i in e.items()]
```

**Output**:

```
[{'grade': '1', 'current_student_sum': 1611, 'past_student_sum': 1611}, {'grade': '3', 'current_student_sum': 1598, 'past_student_sum': 1598}, {'grade': '2', 'current_student_sum': 1631, 'past_student_sum': 1631}]
```

Answer (score 1):

This could help you.

```
your_list = [
             {'grade': '1', 'past_student_sum': 1611},
             {'grade': '2', 'past_student_sum': 1631},
             {'grade': '3', 'past_student_sum': 1598},
             {'grade': '1', 'current_student_sum': 1611},
             {'grade': '2', 'current_student_sum': 1631},
             {'grade': '3', 'current_student_sum': 1598}
             ]



from itertools import groupby

result = []
key_func = lambda x: x['grade']

for i, j in groupby(sorted(your_list, key=key_func), key=key_func):
    group = {}
    for k in j:
        group.update(k)
    result.append(group)

print(result)
# [{'grade': '1', 'current_student_sum': 1611, 'past_student_sum': 1611}, {'grade': '2', 'current_student_sum': 1631, 'past_student_sum': 1631}, {'grade': '3', 'current_student_sum': 1598, 'past_student_sum': 1598}]
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer [the answer by Patrick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49053663/778533) myself. Are you allowed to use pandas? Then you can use [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.group_by.html) and [to_dict](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html). Also needed are [sum](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) and [reset_index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html).

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(grade_list).groupby('grade').sum().reset_index().to_dict('records')
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import itertools

/////


i = 0
for item1, item2 in itertools.izip_longest(listone,listtwo):
    listthree[i] = dict(item1, **item2)
    i += 1
```

I'd recommend having a look at itertools though as there are more efficient ways of doing this and there may be a method for this.

Also this is assuming the lists are the same size.

See the answer below for more on iterating

[How to iterate through two lists in parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663807/how-to-iterate-through-two-lists-in-parallel)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1663826/5990760